# Is there a DNS cache that can automatically re-resolve its cache around the TTL timeout?

Tags: bind, internal-dns, dnsmasq

This is for a server setup with a wobbly upstream DNS for company internal server names. Sometimes, when an entry has fallen from the cache due to TTL, and our system tries to resolve it, the upstream doesn’t answer; then our system sort of falls apart. The domains that are requested are fairly fixed.

Is there a DNS cache for Linux which still honors TTL (don’t need to ask again for X amount of time) but where it will attempt to refresh (with exp. back-off) the cache around the time the TTL has expires? And in the mean time probably returning the old answer, like a grace period.

Currently we are leaning to moving the caching into the application & database. Which seems a bit iffy to me.

It appears some commercial router appliances call this “FQDN Refresh”. But I can’t really find the config to do that in the few open source packages I looked at. It’s probably there, but slightly differently formulated.

Comment: Why not use a different "upstream" DNS server?

Comment: It's a large company's DNS server that serves where the internal servers are on the internal network. There is no other canonical source for this data that we need. You can't just ask 8.8.8.8 about the internal network structure of some company.

Comment: You might want to add those details to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Most Caching servers have the ability to fetch resources that are due to expire in unbound this feature is called prefetch

> prefetch: yes or no
>
> If yes, message cache elements are prefetched
> before they expire to  keep  the  cache  up to date.  Default is no.
> Turning it on gives about 10 percent more traffic and load on the
> machine, but popular items do not expire from the cache.

RFC 8767 also allows caches to return expired data if they are unable to refresh there cache.  one can enable this in unbound with

> serve-expired-client-timeout: msec
>
> Time  in milliseconds before replying to the client with expired
> data.  This essentially  enables  the  serve-stale  behavior  as
> specified in RFC 8767 that first tries to resolve before immedi-
> ately responding with expired data.  A recommended value per RFC
> 8767  is  1800.   Setting  this to 0 will disable this behavior.
> Default is 0.

[bind prefetch](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01122) isc post on [serve-stale](https://www.isc.org/blogs/2020-serve-stale/)